# which() function in filter() with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

I am trying to filter a data set then set the outliers to the mean. Sample data frame:

```
structure(list(INDEX = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), TARGET_WINS = c(39, 
70, 86, 70, 82, 75), TEAM_BATTING_H = c(1445, 1339, 1377, 1387, 
1297, 1279), TEAM_BATTING_2B = c(194, 219, 232, 209, 186, 200
), TEAM_BATTING_3B = c(39, 22, 35, 38, 27, 36), TEAM_BATTING_HR = c(13, 
190, 137, 96, 102, 92), TEAM_BATTING_BB = c(143, 685, 602, 451, 
472, 443), TEAM_BATTING_SO = c(842, 1075, 917, 922, 920, 973), 
    TEAM_BASERUN_SB = c(NA, 37, 46, 43, 49, 107), TEAM_BASERUN_CS = c(NA, 
    28, 27, 30, 39, 59), TEAM_BATTING_HBP = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), TEAM_PITCHING_H = c(9364, 
    1347, 1377, 1396, 1297, 1279), TEAM_PITCHING_HR = c(84, 191, 
    137, 97, 102, 92), TEAM_PITCHING_BB = c(927, 689, 602, 454, 
    472, 443), TEAM_PITCHING_SO = c(5456, 1082, 917, 928, 920, 
    973), TEAM_FIELDING_E = c(1011, 193, 175, 164, 138, 123), 
    TEAM_FIELDING_DP = c(NA, 155, 153, 156, 168, 149)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Using `dplyr`, I filter the outliers, then attempt to mutate the TEAM_FIELDING_E column based on the corrected (non-outlier) mean:

```
train %>% 
  filter(which(boxplot.stats(train$TEAM_FIELDING_E)$out %in% train$TEAM_FIELDING_E, arr.ind = TRUE) == TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(
    TEAM_FIELDING_E = NA,
    TEAM_FIELDING_E = mean(train$TEAM_FIELDING_E)
  )
```

This returns error `Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 2276, not 303` (the original data set contains 303 `TEAM_FIELDING_E` outliers and 2276 rows). How do I utilize `filter()` such that my `mutate()` will only affect those filtered rows?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? How do you define outliers?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the outlying values of `TEAM_FIELDING_E` with the mean value. I'm trying to do so by filtering those outlying values, then applying a `mutate()` that will transform the outlying values (thereby correcting the overarching `train$TEAM_FIELDING_E`) and then mutating those NAs into the corrected mean. The outliers are being defined by the standard `coef = 1.5` of `boxplot.stats()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `dplyr` verbs, use bare variable names and not using `[[` or `$`.  Additionally if you're trying to filter on a value, you can just filter on the value directly rather than trying to use `which` to determine the position of the match.

For this case, you can get what you want with an `if_else` within `mutate`.

```
out <- boxplot.stats(train$TEAM_FIELDING_E)$out

 train %>% 
  mutate(TEAM_FIELDING_E = if_else(TEAM_FIELDING_E %in% out, mean(TEAM_FIELDING_E[!(TEAM_FIELDING_E %in% out)]), TEAM_FIELDING_E))
```

Comment: In this case, is `out` a pre-defined vector of outliers, or does it exist within dplyr as a function of some sort?

Comment: My apologies, forgot to include that bit of my code in the answer.  Fixed.